# Realm filter strings with different table view sections

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I have a table view with at max 27 sections (A-Z + #)

Section A contains all objects where the name begins with "A" etc. My objects in this case are of type `Artist` and have a `name` property.

```
private var sectionIndices: [String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","#"]

for beginningLetter in self.sectionIndices {
  print("Finding artists for \(beginningLetter)")
  let artists: Results<Artist>
  if beginningLetter == "#" {
    artists = self.artists.filter("NOT (name[0] IN %@)", self.sectionIndices)
  } else {
    artists = self.artists.filter("name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", beginningLetter).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
  }
}
```

So filtering works great for everything but the # section. Essentially every artist that has a name which starts with a non-alphabetical letter should be in there. "21 Savage", "6ix9ine", "2 Pac", etc.

MATCHES for some reason do not work, I tried

`name MATCHES %@` but realm does not really support that.

I'm looking for a filter that gives me that behaviour - IN operator on `name[0]` also does not work (and is inefficient).

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly Realm indeed doesn't support the `MATCHES` operator of `NSPredicate`. One possible workaround for your specific issue is to use the `BEGINSWITH` operator with all possible single digits and make a compound predicate using `OR`s with all digits.

```
let startsWithNumberPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH '0' OR name BEGINSWITH '1' OR name BEGINSWITH '2' OR name BEGINSWITH '3' OR name BEGINSWITH '4' OR name BEGINSWITH '5' OR name BEGINSWITH '6' OR name BEGINSWITH '7' OR name BEGINSWITH '8' OR name BEGINSWITH '9'")
```

Then you simply need to use this `startsWithNumberPredicate` in case `beginningLetter == "#"` to find all `Artist`s whose `name` property starts with a number.

```
private var sectionIndices: [String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","#"]

for beginningLetter in self.sectionIndices {
  print("Finding artists for \(beginningLetter)")
  let artists: Results<Artist>
  if beginningLetter == "#" {
    artists = self.artists.filter(startsWithNumberPredicate, self.sectionIndices)
  } else {
    artists = self.artists.filter("name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", beginningLetter).sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using adding a property to the Realm object that would be "sortLetter" or something like that that would add itself the "#" if it's not an "alphabetical" letter? This way there would be the same behavior, not any `if` test.

Comment: @Larme you cannot filter queries based on computed properties, so that wouldn't be any better than using Swift's `filter` and using a closure for filtering